# jQuery Client Side Form Validation not persisting

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have searched with no success for a resolution to this, my form seems to submit and validate correctly. When errors are found, the fields should be highlighted and a message is displayed, and this works, but it does not STAY highlighted.

The desired behavior is for the message to remain and the highlight to stay until the form is submitted again. Now it "blinks" just long enough so I know the code is running. It is easier to see then read about. I made a test page in order to help isolate the issue: http://img.shikadi.com/testpage.html

(I realize the form is not submitting anywhere yet. It will submit to a simple php script that will re-validate and send an email to me. I'd like to get this client side validation working before I tackle that)

Comment: Welcome on SO. It is really hard to help you with so little details you gave us. Please edit your own post and add relevant information, such as Code. I also suggest that you have a look to our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I did include full code on the test page. I guess I could include it in my question but it seemed too long.

Comment: I've checked the code, I think you should have pasted it in there (not the whole HTML, just the logic). You will know for the next time. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
#contact form {
width: 98%;
max-width: 600px;
height: auto;
}

#contact input, button, textarea {
font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
position: relative;
margin: 0.25rem 0;
padding: 2px 4px;
width: 48%;
width: calc(50% - 14px);
}

#contact .left {
float: left;
}

#contact .right {
float: right;
}

#contact textarea {
resize: none;
overflow: auto;
height: 165px;
width: 99%;
width: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.hidden {
display: none;
}

.error {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 170);
opacity:0.8;
}
</style>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
        <section id="contact">
            <h1>Contact Me</h1>
            <div id="errors" class="hidden"><small>* Your message was not sent.<br>Please revise the highlighted fields.</small></div>
            <form name="contactme" id="contact-form" method="post" action="form.php" onSubmit=" return submitContactForm();">
            <input class="name left" type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" class="line" value="name" onfocus="if (this.value=='name') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='name';"/>
            <input class="email right" type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" class="line" value="email" onfocus="if (this.value=='email') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='email';"/>
            <textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" class="message" onfocus="if (this.value=='message') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='message';"/>message</textarea>
            <button class="right" type="submit" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
            </form>
        </section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
validateEmail = function(email){
   var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
   return pattern.test(email);
}

submitContactForm = function () {
    var form = $("#contact-form");

    var postData = {};
    postData.name = form.find('input.name').val();
    postData.email = form.find('input.email').val();
    postData.message = form.find('textarea.message').val();

    var errors = new Array();
    if (postData.name == null || postData.name == '' || postData.name == 'name') {
        errors.push('Name is required.');
        $("input.name").addClass("error");
    }
    if (postData.email == null || postData.email == '' || postData.email == 'email') {
        $("input.email").addClass("error");
        errors.push('Please enter a valid email.');
    } else if (!validateEmail(postData.email)) {
        $("input.email").addClass("error");
        errors.push('Please enter a valid email.');
    }
    if (postData.message == null || postData.message == '' || postData.message == 'message') {
        $("textarea.message").addClass("error");
        errors.push('Message is required.');
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {

        $("#errors").show();
        return false;
   }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! It looks like you just added `return false;` is that right? Can you explain why this works?

Comment: Yes, function returns false, in case that there are validation errors, and form will not be submitted. http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: No explanation? The link in your comment is cool, but you should inclure the explanation here, so if the link break in few years, the information will still be here and your answer will remain valuable. ;)

Comment: @ForceMagic, my answer is valuable, and i don't know why people voted is as 'not useful'?! skihadi asked for help, recognized what i did in code, and he can do some research, if he need further explanations about it... I don't know explanation, actually, (and i don't care too much, as long as code works) i just know that when function return false -> form will not be submitted.

Comment: See How do I write a good answer to a question? it might give you some clues. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/181303 Plus, people consider a good answer when there are some explanations, not just the working code.

Comment: Ok, i will try to explain, i don't have/know better and deeper explanation than one i already posted in first comment. I thought it is enough for purpose (simple form problem)? English is not my first language, obviously. So, link to some useful source of information is better. About broken links... well... what to say - one day this site will, maybe, not exist (sooner or later), and then even greatest answers will not be 'valuable'. :) I am using stackoverflow to find fastest possible solutions to coding problems -> and i got it here! Let's leave deep philosophical discussions for forums.

Comment: Your level of english doesn't matter, it is not my first language as well. But just so you know, you can always edit your own post to add relevant informations :) You can even copy/paste important sentences from another website as long as you link your reference ;)

Comment: Thanks nevermind, I appreciate your answer, and the code works, like you said. That is what I came for :)

Answer (score 0):

add the `.preventDefault()` method and try again
its helping by preventing the default even of the button

remove the "onclick" property and use jQuery instead.

```
$("#right").click(function (e) {

e.preventDefault();
var form = $("#contact-form");

var postData = {};
postData.name = form.find('input.name').val();
postData.email = form.find('input.email').val();
postData.message = form.find('textarea.message').val();

var errors = new Array();
if (postData.name == null || postData.name == '' || postData.name == 'name') {
    errors.push('Name is required.');
    $("input.name").addClass("error");
}
if (postData.email == null || postData.email == '' || postData.email == 'email') {
    $("input.email").addClass("error");
    errors.push('Please enter a valid email.');
} else if (!validateEmail(postData.email)) {
    $("input.email").addClass("error");
    errors.push('Please enter a valid email.');
}
if (postData.message == null || postData.message == '' || postData.message == 'message') {
    $("textarea.message").addClass("error");
    errors.push('Message is required.');
}

if (errors.length > 0) {
    $("#errors").show();
```

}
}
}